# Save the state of multiple check boxes and reload them on application launch

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently attempting to save the state of multiple check boxes, and it's going pretty horribly. My goal is to **save the state of multiple check boxes on my Form2** (into any file: ini, txt, reg...), and then next time the user launches the application, the check boxes should be in the same state they were when the program was closed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this really isn't working out for me...
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

For small apps, I use to keep the state of this kind of UIs in a class (e.g. in your case a list of booleans for the checkboxes), and then serialize/deserialize the class into an XML file.

BTW, I usually save it the the IsolatedStorage.

Comment: +1 for mentioning IsolatedStorage.Thanks, haven't seen that before but seems way helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Settings.settings file that Visual Studio generates for you. Create some new settings for your check boxes (one each), and then use the class generated by VS to store and restore the values.